# How to save the data in a variable within the PHP file and return it as a response (return to the ajax call)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building a school database for my homework.I have issues with receiving a JSON object from PHP as I understood. I managed to sent data to my PHP file. I would like to return it as a response to the Ajax call.I ve received an error as 'No response data available for this request' on my Firefox console.Thanks in advance for your help.

index.html:

```
 <form class="ajaxForm" method="post" action="./Controller/CourseController.php">
```

Custom.js:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready!");

        $('body').click('submit', '.ajaxForm', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this)[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);

            formData.append('submit', $('.submitted-button').attr('name'));


            var dataArray = {
                id: '111',
                title: 'foo'
            };

            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);

            function returnwasset(){
            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: jsonString,
                // THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING:
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function () {
                    alert(response);
```

CourseController.php

```
<?php    

include '../Service/DbTableCourse.php';  

$link = connectToDatabase();
$sql = "SELECT * from courses";
$rows = $link->query($sql);    

echo json_encode($action);    
$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($action == 'C') {
    createCourse();
}
if ($action == 'R') {
    readCourse($_GET['id']);
}
if ($action == 'U') {
    updateCourse($_GET['id']);
}
if ($action == 'D') {
    deleteCourse($_GET['id']);
}

function createCourse() {
    $title = htmlspecialchars($_GET['title']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO courses (title) values ('$title')";
    $link = connectToDatabase();
    $val = $link->query($sql);
    if ($val) {
        header('location: ../index.html');
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}    
function readCourse($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * from courses where id ='$id'";
    $link = connectToDatabase();
    $rows = $link->query($sql);

    $row = $rows->fetch_assoc();    

    return $row['title'];
}    
function updateCourse($id) {
    echo $id;
}    
function deleteCourse($id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: `this` has  different context inside `returnwasset()`. SHow how you call that function

Answer (score 0):

You send data with the `POST` method, as set in your JS code :

`$.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    (...)`

The "method" attribute of `<form>` is set to "POST".

The PHP script is waiting for "GET" data so you have to replace `$_GET` by `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

This "response" must come from the success function:

Instead of this:

```
success: function () {
   alert(response);
```

Try this:

```
success: function (response) {
   alert(response);
```

And as @Thierry Leroux said, change the PHP request from `$_GET[` to `$_POST[`

Comment: Thanks for a help but doesnt work. it is still showing on my console under Response section ' No response data available for this request'.